# How to Setup Highmaps Metropolitan Areas?

Tags: javascript, highmaps

I've been looking into the highmaps documentation, but I couldn't find any example or document on displaying metropolitan US areas.
Has anyone had previous experience with metro areas? 
Could you please point me to an example link, documentation or anything that explains metro areas? 
Any help is greatly appreciated. It is hard to find such resources.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that what u are looking for ? http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps

Comment: Not exactly, I already checked their api docs, but that doesn't explain where the coordinates come from for each metro area.